# Simulate tab key

Tags: vue.js

anyone know how to simulate tab key to move through the inputs?

```
<input type="text" @keyup.enter="myfunc">
<input type="text" @keyup.enter="myfunc">
<input type="text" @keyup.enter="myfunc">

new Vue({
  methods: {
    myfunc() {
      //?
    }
  }
});
```

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do it with the help of Vue directive: [vue-focus](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-focus), See Working code [here](http://jsfiddle.net/8y70Lmz3/2/).

You have to put all input inside a div with id:

```
<div id="demo">
  <input type="text" v-focus="focused['0']" v-on:keyup.enter="changeFocus(1, 0)">
  <input type="text" v-focus="focused['1']" v-on:keyup.enter="changeFocus(2, 1)">
  <input type="text" v-focus="focused['2']" v-on:keyup.enter="changeFocus(nil, 2)">
</div>
```

and use this id to mount Vue component:

```
var demo = new Vue({
    el: '#demo',
      mixins: [ VueFocus.mixin ],
    data:{
         focused: {
             "0": true,
             "1": false,
             "2": false
         }
    },
    methods:{   
      changeFocus(bringInFocus, removeFocus){
         if(bringInFocus) this.focused[bringInFocus] = true
         this.focused[removeFocus] = false
      }
    }
})
```

Comment: Yes, but how can i move through the inputs with Enter key?

Comment: working good, I was hoping that there is a simpler way to do this :/

Answer (score -1):

Yes, using vue-focus is definitely the way to go. It can be installed via npm. The documentation is self explanatory, see:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-focus

With respect to the example given by Saurabh above:

```
<div id="demo">
    <input type="text" v-focus="focused['0']" @keyup.enter="changeFocus('0','1')" />
    <input type="text" v-focus="focused['1']" @keyup.enter="changeFocus('1','2')" />
    <input type="text" v-focus="focused['2']" />
</div>
```

Then you can have the following (note that i'm using a directive instead of a mixin, but you can use either):

```
import { focus } from 'vue-focus';

var demo = new Vue({
    el: '#demo',
    directives: { focus: focus },
    data:{
         focused: {
             "0": true,
             "1": false,
             "2": false
         }
    },
    methods:{   
        changeFocus(current, new) {
            this.focused[current] = false;
            this.focused[new] = true;
        }
    }
})
```